# Visual Studio IDE's ToolBox alternative for VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

`Visual Studio IDE` has a nice feature: `ToolBox`, witch gives ability to save and use pieces of boilerplate code:

[image]

Can't find a similar extension for `VSCode`. There many extensions with the similar name but they serve different job and are a bit complicated for me.

Can you suggest me something similar to `ToolBox` please?

P.S. I' not asking about snippets, this is different.

Comment: read the snippets doc page

Comment: I know what is a snippet but ToolBox is different @rioV8

Comment: if you can't find an extension with this functionality, you can write one yourself, it is not that hard to make and VSC can do that with a custom Tree View

Comment: I know that it is possible to write my own extension but my question was not about it
@rioV8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it! [Snippet](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscode-snippet.Snippet) is the true alternative for `ToolBox`.

[image]